# Image inside div doesn't show

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, photo inside the DIV is not shown.
Since I use the masonry grid and site is like Pinterest, I do not want to limit the height of image or inner, so I put the auto, but when I put the auto, or 100%, the image is not displayed, My code is  below.

```css
.inner {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #ECECEC;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.image-box {
 position:relative;
   height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #4D4E56;
}

.image-box .img{
 width: 100%;
    display: block;
   float: left;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <a href="{{ link }}"><div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x550)"></div></a>

</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan In HTML5 it is

Comment: @mplungjan from the question you linked to: "HTML 5 states that the <a> element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)"."

Comment: @mplungjan - Any of those comment specifically? You can run a simple page through a HTML validator and see that it's valid.

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, gonna side with j here. The comments discuss the matter about HTML4, but their consensus, that the MDN agrees with, is that `div` is now permitted.

Comment: I just ran w3 validator. `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ccc</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="inner">
  <a href="#"><div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x550)"></div></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>` **is valid** - more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your height of your image div is set to `auto`, although there is no content inside that div. This means the div's height is actually 0.

Change your height to a set value, and you should be able to see the image.

```
.image-box {
    position:relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #4D4E56;
}
```

Yes, this limits the height which is what you don't want, but how else do you want it? You can easily scale the images to fill the div nicely and keeping ratio by adding:

```
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: my box is like this on www.pinterest.com   , how to acomplish this effect with images height?

Answer (score 2):

of course it doesn't show because the div with the background-image doesn't have a height because it's empty ...

if you don't want to use height, add `padding-bottom:40px` from `.inner` to `.image-box`

and that `.image-box img` is useless because `img` doesn't exist. your image is as `background-image` to the div not an individual `img` element.

so use what css you want on `.image-box` not on a non-existing `.image-box img`

```css
.inner {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #ECECEC;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.image-box {
 position:relative;
   height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #4D4E56;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
   float: left;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <a href="{{ link }}"><div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x550)"></div></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this one:

```
.image-box {
    height: 350px;;
    width: 500px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #4D4E56;
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x550);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="inner">
    <a href="{{ link }}">
        <div class="image-box"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/maky/9xa9eh1r/)

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Code dumps aren't very helpful to most users without some sort of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not right, it shold be like this:

```
<div class="inner">
  <a href="{{ link }}"><span class="image-box" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x550)"></span></a>
</div>
```

Use `<span>` instead of `<div>`. Also `.image-box .img{}` style is not right, since there is no `img` tag inside it. Finally your CSS should be like it is done in answer below:

```
.image-box{
    height: 350px;
    width: 500px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #4D4E56;
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x550);
}
```

Comment: <a> is inline element, whereas <div> is a block element and it's not right to use `block` elements inside `inline` elements. Therefore you should use `<span>` instead.

Comment: But it's perfectly valid HTML syntax in the HTML5 standard. HTML 4 not so much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Comment: yes it might be right in validator, but it's not right way to declare code, it breaks semantics. If you want to use `<div>` then you should replace default `display:block` with `display:inline-block`.

Comment: _"yes it might be right in validator, but it's not right way to declare code, it breaks semantics"_ That's entirely your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

### Background Information:

Background images do not count as content in CSS, as it is only a style that is assigned to an element, like `background-color`. This means that `auto` won't work as there is actually no content in your div, so it has nothing to relate to.

### How to fix it:

To fix this, you need to set your `width` and `height` to actual values, so that there is an actual size your div has to be.

### Modified Code:

```css
.inner {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #ECECEC;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.image-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #4D4E56;
}
.image-box .img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <a href="{{ link }}"><div class="image-box" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x550)"></div></a>

</div>
```